# Apache solr autocomplete not working with numbers

Tags: solr, solr4

I'm new to solr and creating a autosuggest core. The functionality is not working in the following schenario

http://XXXXXXX:8080/solr/autosuggest/select?q=**SPF 20**&debugQuery=true

My schema.xml file configured as follow

```
<field name="NameSuggest" type="whole_text_suggest" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true" />

 <fieldType name="whole_text_suggest" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" 
               generateWordParts="1" 
               generateNumberParts="1"
               catenateWords="1"
               catenateNumbers="1"
               catenateAll="1"
               splitOnCaseChange="1"
               splitOnNumerics="1"
               preserveOriginal="1"
        />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="([^a-z])" replacement=" " replace="all"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" 
                generateWordParts="0" 
                generateNumberParts="0"
                catenateWords="0"
                catenateNumbers="0"
                catenateAll="0"
                splitOnCaseChange="0"
                splitOnNumerics="0"
            />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="([^a-z])" replacement=" " replace="all"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I observed that the numerical digit **"20"** has ignored while pharsing and searched only **SPF**

```
 <lst name="debug">
<str name="rawquerystring">SPF 20</str>
<str name="querystring">SPF 20</str>
<str name="parsedquery">NameSuggest:spf NameSuggest:</str>
<str name="parsedquery_toString">NameSuggest:spf NameSuggest:</str>
```

Please Note: **q=SPF20** (Without space) is working as expected

Please help me resolve this issue:)

Thanks.
Babu

Comment: Your PatternReplaceFilterFactory appears to remove anything that isn't a lowercase letter. Actually, it just matches a single non alpha character. I recommend you fix that (don't rely on replace="all", I'm not sure that's even available in the latest versions of Solr), reindex, and try your query again. If that doesn't work it might be how you have your WordDelimiterFilterFactory configured on your query analyzer.

Comment: Thank you! pattern="([^a-z0-9])" solved my issue:)